# In C, read() is only placing the first two elements of a file into the buffer

Tags: c, buffer, system-calls

I have just starting using the read() function in C and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The function is supposed to use read() to take every token/word from a file and return them individually with a new line character placed after the token. However, when only the first two characters from the file are being placed into the buffer. The rest is just blank space, so the while loop continues forever until it stops because of a segmentation fault.

```
char* get_token(int fd){
        int size = 50;
        char* buffer = (char*) malloc(size);
        int count = 0;
        int read_return = read(fd, buffer, 1);
        if(read_return == -1){
                perror("Reading error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        while(buffer[count] != ' ' || buffer[count] != '\t' || buffer[count] != '\n'){
                read_return = read(fd, buffer, 1);
                if(read_return == -1){
                        perror("Reading error");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                count++;
                if(count == size-2){
                        buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, size+10);
                }
        }
        buffer[count] = '\n';
        return buffer;
}
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `read(fd, buffer, 1);` That writes to the same byte, the first byte of `buffer`, every time.

Comment: @kaylum So then how do I read in one character at a time?

Comment: You are already reading one character at a time. It's just that you are overwriting the same location every time. Try something like `read(fd, &buffer[counter++], 1);`. That is, write into the current slot of the buffer and then move the index to the next slot.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `read` function you are always passing the buffer's memory address without an offset, so it will always write to the first position of your buffer. You should call read like so:

```c
read(fd, buffer + count, 1);
```

Comment: `while(buffer[count] != ' ' || buffer[count] != '\t' || buffer[count] != '\n')` is also wrong because it is always true. `buffer[count]` will never be space, tab and newline at the same time. You probably meant something like `while(!isspace(buffer[count]))`.